# YAML text editor field in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am looking for a convenient way to write and edit YAML in Django admin panel.
Are there any text editors in django admin panel for YAML

Comment: I recently answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479811 doesn’t need any plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by integrating [django-ace](https://github.com/django-ace/django-ace) field and in this we have support for CSS, python, HTML etc also.