# Stylized HTML fields in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I Have `TextField` to store `HTML` text. I want to colorize HTML tags. I use `TinyMCE` but didn't need an HTML editor like WordPress just simple to colorize like IDE, Search a lot but didn't find anything useful, So if you can help I appreciate it.

**My field:**
[image: This is my field that I want to colorize]

**I want output like this but changeable:**

[image: Output something like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using a code editor in Django admin Textarea**

The following is implemented with [CodeMirror](https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror) but you can use any other library ([Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/), etc).

Final result:
[image]

For all the libraries, we need to add some library specific javascript and stylesheet plus some custom code for integration.

Django has pretty flexible [templating](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/) to enable this. We can override the entire template or specific blocks. Detailed documentation can be fond [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template).

To integration CodeMirror, we can override the `admin/base.html` 's `extrahead` block. We will include the required js/css, one extra css for theming and some js to find and apply CodeMirror.

Here, I have create a `admin/base.html` inside my project's configured template directory. This will apply to all the apps and models. There are ways to target an app or model individually - check the office docs.

> This works for JSONField data. You will have to tweak a bit to format
> html or any other language.

> Inspect the page and find id of the textarea you want to target

```
<!-- tested with Django 3.2.9 -->

{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}

{{ block.super }}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/codemirror.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/codemirror.min.css"
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/theme/oceanic-next.min.css"
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        const target = document.getElementById("id_data");
        target.value = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(target.value), null, '  ');
        const config = {
            mode: 'javascript',
            theme: 'oceanic-next',
            lineNumbers: true,
            lineWrapping: true
        }

        const jsonCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(target, config);
        jsonCodeMirror.setSize("100%", 600);
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Multiple textarea inputs can be targeted as well with get element with classname and then looping over the result set and applying the same logic.

For **html formatting**,

you can use this `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js` instead of javascript. Delete the json stringify statement. Change mode to `htmlmixed`.

Comment: Thanks, Armita, but I get a 404 error on extra_customisation.js, Sorry I didn't work with the admin panel too much, that I can't execute your answer, Can you add some detail that how can I add this to admin section and admin HTML and CSS section ?

Comment: All right. I will add this on my ongoing project and update my answer. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Update. With some minor tweaking you can format html as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to override any template

solved by integrating [django-ace](https://github.com/django-ace/django-ace) field and in this we have support for CSS, python, HTML etc also.

Simply use this in django forms and provide the form in django model admin class

#### admin file

```py
from appname import forms

@admin.register(models.Table)
class TableModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = forms.TableModelForm
```

#### form file

```py
from django import forms
from django_ace import AceWidget

class TableModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Table
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'columns': AceWidget(
                mode='json',
                theme='None',
                width='1200px',
                height='500px',
                fontsize='18px',
                showprintmargin=False,
            ),
        }
```